# How to Insert List data in Firebase Cloud Firestore android

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore, retrofit2

I want to insert a list of data in Firestore database and in my case, I am getting only single document entry and inside the loop it is updating entry only here is my code :

```
 ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitManager.getInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<DoctorsResponse> call = apiInterface.getDoctors();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<DoctorsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<DoctorsResponse> call, @NonNull Response<DoctorsResponse> response) {
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();


            final String docId = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("DoctorList").document().getId();


            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.e("@@size", String.valueOf(response.body().getData().size()));
                docDetailsList.addAll(response.body().getData());

                Datum datum = new Datum();
                for (int i = 0; i<docDetailsList.size(); i++){
                    String docDob = docDetailsList.get(i).getFullName();
                    datum.setFullName(docDetailsList.get(i).getFullName());
                    Log.e("@@Docdob", docDob);

                }

                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("DoctorList").document(docId).set(datum).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MembersLists.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<DoctorsResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            Log.e("Error","error ");
        }
    });
```

In the above code I have tried many changes like put firebase query inside loop every time I am getting only a single entry and i am getting all response from backend please help me it's in my priority thank you in advance and I appreciate every response.

Comment: because you have set data on same `docId`.

Comment: I want to insert all list data as a particular document tell me how to generate every time new id

Comment: Thank you brother I really approciate your answer

Comment: Hey @AbhayKoradiya!
Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so that it gives closure to this post?